# Можно ли употреблять деепричастие в безличном предложении?

Tags: деепричастия

Проверив документы, водителей отпустили.

Можно ли употреблять деепричастие в неопределенно-личном предложении?

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя? Лицо-деятель имеется, хотя и неизвестно.

Вот в безличном (как у Вас в названии вопроса)не употребляется,если сказуемое-безличный глагол или категория состояния, потому что если лица нет, то и действие производить некому, зато возможно употребление деепричастного оборота в  предложениях с составным глагольным  сказуемым (там есть потенциальный деятель): Проверив документы, необходимо отпустить водителей.

Answer (score 0):

Проверив документы, их отпустили. Это неопределенно-личное предложение, деепричастие употреблено верно, но стиль сомнительный (кого отпустили?).

Пример:

Проверив документы (вот и пригодился новый паспорт), у них вежливо спросили, не из Рейха ли они будут (Дмитрий Глуховский).